# IndexError: too many indices for array ... an error when running this code

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following error

> > IndexError: too many indices 
> >             for array

when running this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([[208500, 181500,      
               223500, 
           140000, 250000, 143000, 
           307000, 200000, 129900, 
           118000]])

X = np.array([[1710, 1262, 1786, 
           1717, 2198, 1362, 
           1694, 2090, 1774, 
           1077], 
           [2003, 1976, 2001, 
            1915, 2000, 1993, 
            2004, 1973, 1931, 
            1939]])

data=[X, y]

# print data
print(data)

input= np.array(data)
print(input)

# Setup matrices
m = np.shape(input)[0]
X=np.matrix([np.ones(m),input[:,0]]).T
y = np.matrix(input[:,1]).T
```

Could someone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: You likely haven't created your arrays in the you intended to create them. `input` is (2,), so you can't index it with `[:, 0]`.

Comment: One array is (1,10)  shape, the other (2,10).  Since they are different `input` is a 2 element object dtype array, virtually a list of arrays.  What were you expecting?  Why are you using `np.matrix`?  How is the final `y` supposed to differ from the initial `y`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your variable named `input` is a 1D array. You can't use two indexes to access an 1D array. A good example is that you can't access a matrix only with one index or you can't access a vector with two indexes.

You can check the size of `input` if you execute `input.shape`

As I see, you have in the `input` variable a 1D array with two nested arrays. If you want to access the first array, you should execute input[0] and the append the index if the array in that position, for example `input[0][0,0]`

The first array is 2D shape, you can check it if you execute 
`input[0].shape`
So, you should use 2 indexes to access it.

Let me know if you need further help.